# Extract attributes from a JSON node using JSON Path (non-array structure / no extra code)

Tags: json, jsonpath

I'm stuck using JSONPath to extract a list of attributes from a JSON Object / Node without using extra code, just using JSON Path.

**Here is an example of the JSON Object**

```
{
   "MySchema": {
    "fields": {
        "FieldOne": {
            "required": false,
            "type": "long",
        },
        "FieldTwo": {
            "required": false,
            "type": "string",
        },
        "FieldThree": {
            "required": false,
            "type": "string",
        }

    }
}
```

This is just an example, for my production use case, the node ´**fields**´ contains hundreads of sub nodes. And I cannot parse them manually.

Getting the values of each "Field node" is easy by using :

- $MySchema.fields..required
- $MySchema.fields..type

But what about the JSONPath expression to use to get the following list (the name of each node only :

- FieldOne
- FieldTwo
- FieldThree

I didn't find the answer in previous posts, most of them are related to arrays / lists.

Kind regards,

Comment: JSON Path isn't going to return field names, at least not directly. Some implementations support returning the path to matches, but you'd need extra code to extract the field names.

Comment: which implementation or library are you using?

Comment: It's not part of the original jsonpath specification however [Jayway JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#functions) library provides `.keys()` function and [JSONPath Plus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath-plus) provides  `~` for grabbing property names of matching items (as array)